# How to generate Cashflow dates and values automatically from a set of Data?

Tags: google-apps-script

So I am trying to create a returns tracker for my Insurance investments.

I have created a master list in the first sheet and accordingly I am creating cashflow of each policy in the 2nd sheet.

This process of manually entering the dates as per the cashflow is quite tedious and I am sure there is a better way to manage this.

Requesting if you can kindly have a look and see how to create this?

I have created 2 policies, 1 with maturity payout at the end of the policy, and another with payouts every year after the premium term.

[Here is the link to Google sheet - you can view and create a copy of it.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1z3Xus2RYfP-YMICrmiylprs2N9MyqAYACYccZVPlVrI/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot imagine your expected situation from your question. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect?

Comment: I agree with @Tanaike I think more context and clarification about what you are doing in your document is needed to better understand what you want to accomplish.

Comment: My apologies. I’LL explain again- I am trying to model the cash flows the same way it is done in the second sheet. The first sheet has the master sheet and the output needs to be the one in the second sheet. So basically it will fill up the dates and the amounts automatically(based on data fetched from master sheet)and then give me the XIRR.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, from your reply, I cannot still understand your question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: Hello @Tanaike - I truly appreciate your effort. I'll try to explain in a better way once more - So my input will be the _Master Sheet_ , while I need the output to be the _Cashflow_ sheet_ (CF Sheet)

As you can see, the _CF sheet_ is created from the _Master Sheet_ itself. 

What I want is that whenever I enter a policy detail in the _Master Sheet_, a cashflow chart automatically gets created in the _CF Sheet_ with the dates and amounts fetched automatically.

I hope it is clearer now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This process of manually entering the dates as per the cashflow is quite tedious and I am sure there is a better way to manage this.

#### Example: Policy `XXXX1245S`

1. **"Year"** column is a range of dates.

   - First date is the **"Start Date"** in `Cashflow sheet'!J5`
   - Dates increment by 1 year
   - Final date is **x** years after the **"Start Date"** where **x = "Policy term"** `'Cashflow sheet'!J9`
2. Outflow is a number based on the **"Premium amount"** `'Cashflow sheet'!J3`

   - Outflow is included on the **"Start Date"** and for **y** more years, where **y = "Prem. pmt term"** `'Cashflow sheet'!J8`

#### Named Ranges

To make the formula easier to follow I've used named ranges

| Name | Reference | Notes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **pmt** | `'Cashflow sheet'!J8` | Prem. pmt term |
| **pol** | `'Cashflow sheet'!J9` | Policy term |
| **start** | `'Cashflow sheet'!J5` | Start date |
| **prem** | `'Cashflow sheet'!J3` | Premium amount |

#### Formula

The following formula will dynamically create the first three columns <sup>[image]</sup> with as many rows as is required and properly populated.  If the logic for the **"Inflow"** column was better understood, it too could be populated in the same formula.  Frankly the entire table including the information at the top could probably be populated from one formula based solely on the **"Policy No."** if all the required data is stored in the `Master List` sheet.

```
={ "Cashflow", "Year", "Outflow";
    MAP(SEQUENCE(pol+1), LAMBDA(s, 
        { s,(EDATE(start, (s-1)*12)), IF(s<=pmt,-prem,0) })) }
```

[image]

1. A [LAMBDA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12508718) function is used to create the array.
2. A [SEQUENCE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9368244) of numbers representing policy term years is generated and [MAP](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12568985) into the [LAMBDA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12508718) function which applies the formula once for each value in the [SEQUENCE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9368244)
3. **"Cashflow"** column is equal to the position in the [SEQUENCE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9368244), so the mapped value `s` is placed in the first column.
4. In the **"Year"** column [EDATE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3092974) is used to offset the **"Start Date"** by the number of years equal to the mapped value `(s-1)*12`.  The years are multiplied by 12 because [EDATE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3092974) offsets in months.
5. Finally, the **"Outflow"** column is populated with the **"Premium Amount"** if the mapped value `s` is **<=** to the **"Prem. pmt term"**.  If not, the **"Outflow"** column is set to zero.

---

##### *Additional Info*

The [SEQUENCE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9368244) function creates an array of specified dimensions, populated with a number sequence starting at a specified value, and incrementing (stepping) by another specified value.  The only required value, however, is rows (height).

```
Syntax: SEQUENCE(rows, [columns], [start], [step])

=SEQUENCE(5)       // rows=5, cols=1, start=1, step=1
={1;2;3;4;5}           

=SEQUENCE(2,4)     // rows=2, cols=4, start=1, step=1
={1,2,3,4;5,6,7,8}
```

The [MAP](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12568985) function enables mapping a set of values into a [LAMBDA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12508718) function.  Inside the [LAMBDA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12508718) function, a formula can be applied iteratively to each mapped value.  The [LAMBDA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12508718) declares one  (arbitrary) name (variable) for each set of mapped values which the formula uses in order to refer to the current mapped value.

```
# one set of values mapped
=MAP(values, LAMBDA(name, formula))

# two sets of values mapped
=MAP(values1, values2, LAMBDA(name1, name2, formula))
```

So, looking at the initial [MAP](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12568985) and [LAMBDA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12508718) parts of the formula:

```
# - 'pol+1' is sequenced instead of 'pol' because
#    it was noted that the date list was always 1 
#    row longer than the number in "Policy term" 
# - 's+0' is the 'formula' in this example just to 
#    avoid confusing the 'name' and the 'formula'
# - 'pol'=4 in this example
# - 'MAP(values, LAMBDA(name, formula))'

=MAP(SEQUENCE(pol+1), LAMBDA(s, s+0) 
={ 1; 2; 3; 4; 5 }
```

**Now to build the 3 column array:**

- The first row is set as `{ "Cashflow", "Year", "Outflow" }`
- Each row has `s` in the **"Cashflow"** column:
  `{ 1; 2; 3; 4; 5 }`
- the "Start date" `start`, offset by `s-1 years`, goes in column 2
- `start` is offset `s-1 years` instead of `s years` because `start` is always the first date in the table, therefore the first  calculation must be `start+0yr` not `start+1yr`:
  `{ start+0yr; start+1yr; start+2yr; start+3yr; start+4yr }`
- lastly, the negative **"Premium amount"** (`-prem`) is placed in column 3, but only if the date in column 2 falls within the **"Prem. pmt term"** (`pmt`), otherwise a `0` is placed instead

```
# - Instead of 'start+(s-1)years', as EDATE
#   offsets in months (not years), the calculation
#   is adapted by multiplying by 12:
#   '(EDATE(start, (s-1)*12)'
# - 'pol'=4, 'start'=2/28/2021,
#   'prem'=199, `pmt`=3   

={ "Cashflow", "Year", "Outflow";
    MAP(SEQUENCE(pol+1), LAMBDA(s, 
      { s,(EDATE(start, (s-1)*12)),
        IF(s<=pmt,-prem,0)         }
    ))
 }

= { "Cashflow", "Year", "Outflow";
    1, 2/28/2021, -199;
    2, 2/28/2022, -199;
    3, 2/28/2023, -199;
    4, 2/28/2024, 0;
    5, 2/28/2025, 0 }
```

Comment: Thanks! This is brilliant. 

I will work on improving structure of Master sheet such that inflow can also be modeled using this formula.

One question - I'm still confused on the `LAMBDA(s,{ s,(EDATE(start, (s-1)*12)), IF(s<=pmt,-prem,0) })) }`

The `s` is the mapped value(meaning its the value that's mapped into the sequence if I understand correctly?) , but why are we offsetting it using edate?

Comment: Added ***Additional Info*** section to address

Comment: Hey, so we use the {} in the formula part of lambda function and use `{s,s+0,s+1}` so that each formula is mapped across `Cashflow`,`Year`,`Outflow`. Hope my understanding is correct? Was there only 1 column, we would've used normal round brackets right?

Comment: Yes-ish.  I wouldn't use `{ s, s+0, s+1 }` to describe it since `s` means something in the formula and that array doesn't match anything in the formula, but `{ val1, val2, val3 }` is indeed a 3 column array which is what the formula builds.  The lambda itself builds an array that is `pol+1` rows long and each row is made up of those 1x3 arrays that are generated for each set of mapped values. As you said if it was only one column we wouldn't need `{}`

Comment: Is there a way for me to put in a defined value in one of the rows? So rather than entering the formula in each row, I want the 1st column in 1st row to have a default value `x` while the rest of the rows in 1st column can have the `val1` formula.

Comment: You could do it if the value is pulled from somewhere else such as a helper column, and the formula is updated to check same.  Arrayformula overwrites the range so will complain if any values already in range